# How to handle updates to old questions

Tags: discussion

After seeing the update to [Is Clang/LLVM ready for prime time?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17442/is-clang-llvm-ready-for-prime-time), I'm wondering how to rate the other answers. A lot has happened between the moment when the question was posted, and the update.
Most answers seem dated now.

I was wondering how to deal with a situation like this. Should we update votes? (if any were cast)

To me, the question itself seems to be very 'temporally localized'.

I don't think the update to the lead answer was a bad thing in itself, it's just such a stark contrast to a) the question and b) the other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the rate at which software development changes, I don't think it is feasible to keep the answers updated to the latest trends/changes or even to revise the votes on all of them.

I think it is best to view all questions and answers in view of the time-frame in which they were written, but it might be a consideration in the closure of a question, if it has been taken over by the current status quo (like in the referenced Clang/LLVM question).